# How could parent window open 2 children windows ("childA" and "childB"), then have childA update content in childB?

Tags: javascript

I would like to have a web page open two children windows ( childA, and childB ).  Then, have javascript code in ChildA perform an update of a field value in childB.

How would this be done? Sample code would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: ONLY possible if all pages come from the same server

Answer (score 1):

childA can communicate with parent and parent can communicate that info to childB.

define a function

```
window.update = function(data){
    window.childB.field = data;
}

window.childA = window.open(url1);
window.childB = window.open(url2);
```

In childA window call

```
window.opener.update(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to keep a reference of the other window inside the childB :

Parent

```
window.childA = window.open(...);
window.childB = window.open(...);
window.childB.childA = window.childA;
```

ChildB

```
window.childA.whatever();
```